# Запись данных через форму в mysql с помощью PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Не получается вставить данные через форму в mysql, используя PHP, скорее всего из-за даты, т.к. используя данный код для вставки строковых данных всё отрабатывало корректно. В базе данных поле date записано в формате DATE, в форме в html используется:

`<input type="date" id="appointment" name="appointment">`

В чем может быть проблема?

Сама функция:

```
function insert ($table, $params){
     global $pdo;
     $i = 0;
     $coll = '';
     $mask = '';
     foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
         if ($i === 0){
             $coll = $coll . "$key";
             $mask = $mask . "'" . "$value" . "'";
         }else{
              $coll = $coll . ", $key";
             $mask = $mask . ", '" . "$value" . "'";
         }
         $i++;
     }

$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($coll) VALUES ($mask)";
$query = $pdo->prepare ($sql);
$query->execute();
dbCheckError($query);
 }
```

Вызов:

```
<?php
    include ("connection.php");
    
    if (isset ($_POST['fname'])){
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['appointment']));
        $time = $_POST['time'];
        $review = $_POST['review'];
    
        $post = [
        'fio' => $fname,
        'email' => $email,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'type' => $type,
        'date' => $date,
        'time' => $time,
        'description' => $review
        ];
    
    insert ('vet_center.application', $post);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: ```foreach ($params as $key => $value)....``` => ```$mask = implode(',',$params); $coll = implode(',',array_keys($params));```

Comment: Я так понимаю мне необходимо заменить данный код: $coll = $coll . "$key"; $mask = $mask . "'" . "$value" . "'"; на предложенный Вами, однако все равно не помогает(

Comment: Это просто более короткая версия записи вашего цикла, всего в несколько команд. А ответ на вопрос доступен по ссылке с которой вопрос закрыли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5